# Specify multiple events to trigger a StringValidator?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, events

I would like to validate a Flex `TextInput` using a `StringValidator`. I have found that I can do this like so:

```
<mx:StringValidator source="{myTextInput}"
                    property="text"
                    triggerEvent="{TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT}"/>
```

However, I would like to validate the text not just on the `textInput` [event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html#event%3atextInput), but also on the focusOut [event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html#FOCUS_OUT).

```
                    triggerEvent="{FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT}"
                    triggerEvent="{TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT}"/>
```

However, redefining `triggerEvent` twice like this is illegal. Is it possible to trigger the `StringValidator` based on multiple different events?

Comment: You'll have to write your own event handler for the FOCUS_OUT and I believe call the validate() method on the validator instance.In my experience, that approach is much more common than using a triggerEVent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

mxml code

```
    <mx:StringValidator source="{myTextInput}" property="text"
        triggerEvent="validateInput"/>

    <mx:TextInput id="myTextInput" 
             textInput="inputEvent(event)" 
             focusOut="inputEvent(event)"/>
```

handler

```
    private function inputEvent(event:*):void {
     dispatchEvent(new Event("validateInput"));
}
```

other variation

handler

```
    private function inputEvent(event:*):void {             
    myValidator.validate();
}
```

mxml

```
    <mx:StringValidator id="myValidator" source="{myTextInput}" property="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just attach two validator to the same field. 
The only problem is that there are situations where both event could be triggered.
For example if you show a pop up when on text input tou will also focus out.

Howevere this is a working example:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;

                protected function stringvalidator1_validHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
                {
                    trace("Validated testInput");                   
                }

                protected function stringvalidator1_invalidHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
                {
                    trace("Invalidated testInput");                 

                }
                protected function stringvalidator2_validHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
                {
                    trace("Validated focusOut");                    
                }

                protected function stringvalidator2_invalidHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
                {
                    trace("Invalidated focusOut");                  

                }


            ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:StringValidator source="{fname}" minLength="4" maxLength="20"
                            property="text" valid="stringvalidator1_validHandler(event)" 
                            invalid="stringvalidator1_invalidHandler(event)"
                            triggerEvent="{TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT}"/>
        <mx:StringValidator source="{fname}" minLength="4" maxLength="20"   
                            property="text" valid="stringvalidator2_validHandler(event)" 
                            invalid="stringvalidator2_invalidHandler(event)"
                            triggerEvent="{FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT}"/>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Panel title="StringValidator Example"
             width="75%" height="75%"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <mx:Form left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
            <mx:FormItem label="Enter a name between 4 and 20 characters: ">
                <s:TextInput id="fname" width="100%"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

A validator is attached only one trigger event. If you want triggering more events, so you have to add more validators where the source is the same field but you change the eventTrigger property.

So, you have:

```
<mx:StringValidator source="{myTextInput}"
property="text"
triggerEvent="{TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT}"/>
```

and:

```
<mx:StringValidator source="{myTextInput}"
property="text"
triggerEvent="{FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT}"/>.
```

IMHO, I'd add only one validator on focusOut, so you let free user write every bestiality but when you leave the control, you'll do all check and validation.

Answer (score 0):

TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT won't detect backspace and delete key events.  Use Event.CHANGE instead.